# We went until / as far as Madrid?

Tags: grammar

I noticed a contradiction in Cambridge Dictionary. It says that "We don’t use until or till to talk about distance; we use as far as", but at the same time it cites "as far as" as one of the meanings of "until". How can both be correct?

According to English Grammar Today (from Cambridge Dictionary):

> We don’t use until or till to talk about distance; we use as far as:
>
> We had to drive as far as Liverpool for the last hockey match that I
>   played.
>
> Not: We had to drive until Liverpool …

But the dictionary itself says:

> Until = as far as: You should stay on the train until Manchester and then
>   change.

Comment: You should stay on the train until (it arrives at) Manchester and then change.

Comment: @user121863 - So can I say "We went until Madrid"?

Comment: And why is it not correct to say "We had to drive until Liverpool" when it can mean "We had to drive until (we arrived at) Liverpool"?

Comment: Because it's English. Everything is dependent on context. The train is on a schedule so it's correlated with time. You couldn't say "we went until Madrid" but you could say "we sang '99 bottles of beer on the wall' until Madrid, but were too hoarse to sing until we got to Barcelona."

Comment: I think it's because there is an element of agency involved in driving whereas when you take the train you are passive. When you are travelling by car you have a much closer relationship with the driver (which may be you) than you do with the the driver of a train and, as @Spencer says, the train is running on a schedule and probably goes past Manchester whereas the driver will probably either park the car or turn round and go back when you have got to your destination. You _can_ use 'as far as' when you are travelling passively but you _can't_ use 'until' on its own unless you _are_ passive.